# juju can not start lxc machine

Tags: juju, kvm-virtualization, lxc

I am trying juj on an openvz VPS. when I try **juju bootstrap** it says:

```
uploading tools for series [precise trusty]
Logging to /home/danialbehzadi/.juju/local/cloud-init-output.log on remote host
Bootstrapping Juju machine agent
Starting Juju machine agent (juju-agent-danialbehzadi-local)
```

But the machine log has an error about **Module msr not found** and **no kvm containers possible**: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9505262/

How ever the juju status is:

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
services: {}
```

If I type for example:

> juju deploy wordpress

the juju status would change to:

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state-info: 'error executing "lxc-create": lxc: call to cgmanager_move_pid_abs_sync(freezer)
    failed: invalid request; Container already exists'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
services:
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:trusty/wordpress-1
    exposed: false
    relations:
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVZ is not a real VPS, but an advanced container. This has the advantages that it's cheap because you don't have the virtualisation overhead. However, it also means that what you can do with it is limited.

**This limitation prevents you from creating LXC containers.** Specifically in this case, one of the problems is that the msr kernel module is not loaded, and you do not have permissions to load it.

This is quite normal on a container-based virtual server, because the kernel is shared among all the virtual servers. Being able to change the kernel would be a very big security risk...